# Subtract number by click till it reaches zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, click, subtraction

I want the content of `#rad-btn::before` to subtract everytime `#rad-btn` is pushed till it eventually reaches zero (after 12 times pushing).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#rad-btn").click(function() {});
});
```

```css
#rad-btn::before {
  content: "12";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="rad-btn" href="#">
  <img src="img/rad-btn2.png">
</a>
```

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: `<a id="rad-btn" href="#"><img src="img/rad-btn2.png"></a>` That is all

Answer (score 1):

Use `data-*`, `attr()` at `content` to reference the `data-*` attribute, `Element.dataset`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#rad-btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.dataset.btn > 0) {
      this.dataset.btn = --(this.dataset.btn)
    }
  })
})
```

```css
#rad-btn::before {
  content: attr(data-btn);
}
#rad-btn {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<a id="rad-btn" href="#" data-btn="12">
  <img src="" alt="image">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css `attr()` to set the content then adjust that attribute value

```js
$('#rad-btn').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).attr('data-num', function(_, curr) {
    return curr - 1 > 0 ? curr - 1 : 0;
  });
});
```

```css
#rad-btn::before {
  content: attr(data-num);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="rad-btn" href="#" data-num="12"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for another approach, or cannot change markup you can use:

- [**`counter-reset`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset) with a starting value of `12`.
- [**`counter-increment`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/counter-increment) with a negative value, to decrease by `1` each time the anchor is clicked.
- `counter()` css function in the `content` property of pseudo-element
  `::before` to display the number.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  (function() {
    var x = -1;
    $("#rad-btn").on("click.mycounter", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (x === -12) {
        $(this).off("click.mycounter");
      }
      $(this).css("counter-increment", "mycounter " + x);
      x--;
    });
  })();
});
```

```css
#rad-btn {
  counter-reset: mycounter 12;
}
#rad-btn::before {
  content: counter(mycounter);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="rad-btn" href="#">
  <img src="" alt="image">
</a>
```